# How do you clean B737 Wheel Wells?

Tags: boeing-737, landing-gear, cleaning

just wondering, is there any tools used to clean main/nose landing gear bay? I was thinking some machine with steam water or hot water high pressure and solvents.

wondering what is the best cleaning options for bays of B737 or A320 wheel wells.

or... perhaps brush and wiper? a little harder to remove CPCP

Answer (score 2):

One option is to [dry](https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/cf7773/dry_ice_blasting_the_nose_landing_gear_wheel_well/) ice [blast](https://www.cryonomic.com/en/applications/1271/dry-ice-blasting-in-automotive-industry/cleaning-airplane-parts) it.

Comment: best idea so far but any limitations regarding the pressure? AMM lets you use it? and what is the best quality machine for this

Comment: @SamerAlKasaji those links have some machines listed, you will need to check your aircrafts documentation or contact Boeing for proper procedures and limitations.